# email html signature don't work on apple mail

Tags: html, html-email

Have the following html signature code for apple mail:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<table border="0" width="530" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="250"><img src="http://www.sechseläuten-ball.ch/mail/SB_logo_mail.jpg" width="230" height="190" alt="Sechseläuten-Ball"></td>
            <td valign="bottom" width="280" style="color:#8d8d8d; font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size:16px;padding-bottom: 10px;"><strong>Ball Comit&eacute; Sechsel&auml;utenball 2016</strong><br><br>Zunft zur Meisen<br><a href="mailto:comite@sechsel&auml;uten-ball.ch" style="text-decoration:none; color:#8d8d8d;">comite@sechsel&auml;uten-ball.ch</a><br><a href="http://www.sechseläuten-ball.ch" style="text-decoration:none; color:#8d8d8d;">www.sechsel&auml;uten-ball.ch</a></td>
         </tr>
</table>
```

If i copy & paste to apple mail signature it all looks good, the picture is left to the text like [http://www.sechseläuten-ball.ch/mail/sb_signatur.html](http://www.sechsel%C3%A4uten-ball.ch/mail/sb_signatur.html)

But after saving the text is moving below the image. Anybody any idea why?

thanks for help

best regards
thomas

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table border="0" width="530" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><img src="http://www.sechseläuten-ball.ch/mail/SB_logo_mail.jpg" width="230" height="190" alt="Sechseläuten-Ball"></td>
            <td valign="bottom" style="color:#8d8d8d; font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size:16px;padding-bottom: 10px;"><strong>Ball Comit&eacute; Sechsel&auml;utenball 2016</strong><br><br>Zunft zur Meisen<br><a href="mailto:comite@sechsel&auml;uten-ball.ch" style="text-decoration:none; color:#8d8d8d;">comite@sechsel&auml;uten-ball.ch</a><br><a href="http://www.sechseläuten-ball.ch" style="text-decoration:none; color:#8d8d8d;">www.sechsel&auml;uten-ball.ch</a></td>
         </tr>
</table>
```